# How to move SQLite library files to subdirectory inside a .NET project ouput?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Right now “x86” and “x64” folders are created in the root of Release folder with “SQLite.Interop.dll” file inside them. As well other dll-files of SQLite library reside in the root. How to put all SQLite necessary files to subfolder inside root (e.g. Release\SQLite) and make sure everything works?

Comment: Doesn't it work how it is? Why do you need the files elsewhere?

Comment: I just want my root directory to stay clean. There are other files related to application. I don't want them interfere with 3rd party lib files.

Comment: Then I guess your problem is more general than using SQLite, because most references or packages will place a DLL file in your binary folder. Look for deployment strategies for .NET applications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312754/should-i-deploy-interop-x-dll-files-with-net-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NuGet package manager is placing those folders with “SQLite.Interop.dll” file inside. I just added references to SQLite by myself and didn't include that “SQLite.Interop.dll” (works without it), set a `Copy Local` property of references on `false` so that they won't copy to bin directory. Then I placed libraries inside subdirectory like a wanted manually. After, I just needed to put [probing path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) in `App.config` so that runtime will search for assemblies in specified subdirectories too.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <probing privatePath="MySubdirectory1;MySubdirectory2"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

With this approach one should copy libraries to output directory manually but this worth it root directory to be clean.