# How to use interop.x.dll file in a C# project if the dll file is missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am a noob in C# programming. 
I am currently trying to run a C# project in visual Studio. While building the project I am getting a particular assembly or directory file is not found.
In the .csproj file, the com directory of the library is present :-

```
<COMReference Include="SREYELINKLib">
  <Guid>{F8FB49B9-9448-4045-BB1F-9DEA1F98B7E6}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>2</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
</COMReference>
```

When I look into the bin of the folder , I get the file Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll.
However, the .dll file is not present in the project. 
How do I resolve this compilation error?

Comment: Do a search for the file SREYELINKLib on your machine.  The file either needs to be in the project bin folder, the full path needs to be specified, or your environmental variable LIB need to have the location of where the file is located.

Comment: In my project bin folder interop.SREYELINKLib.dll is present but not SREYELINKLib.dll. Also, my environment variable does not have a LIB variable. I am using windows 10.

Comment: Try `<EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>`

Comment: I tried doing adding <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes> inside the <COMReference> tag; however, it still shows the same error.Should I share my git project for the same?

Comment: Did the `SREYELINKLib` dll import from somewhere? Besides, in some situation, some special com references need only be `non embedding the interop types` so that the project can use it successfully. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642713/passing-an-array-of-structs-to-a-com-interface). And in some cases, `Embed interop types=true` approach sometimes results in strange methods.

Comment: So l suggest you could click on the com reference-->Properties-->set `EmbedInteropTypes` to `False` and then `Copy Local` to `True`. After that, you can see the dll in the bin folder(which is the output path you set)

Comment: In addition, l think `SREYELINKLib` which showed in the `Solution Explorer` really means the `Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll`.l think they represent the same file. You can click the `SREYELINKLib` in the `Solution Explorer` and then see the name in the Property Window. And note if you use this dll in the codes, please use `Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll`not `SREYELINKLib.dll`. If your issue still persists, please share the error message with us.

Comment: Yes. trying it now. Will update once able to reach a headway.

Comment: Hi, did your issue still bother you? And it still exist, please feel free to let us know. It is just a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

> When I look into the bin of the folder , I get the file
>   Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll. However, the .dll file is not present in the
>   project. How do I resolve this compilation error?

The `SREYELINKLib` means `Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll`.They represent the same file. And `Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll` is its full name just like the picture shows below. So when you encounter this, it's not an error, it's normal.

[image]

> While building the project I am getting a particular assembly or
>   directory file is not found. In the .csproj file, the com directory of
>   the library is present :-

**First**, l think you have encountered the build error that the system cannot find the specific com reference. If so:

Since Net 4.0, Microsoft has added `EmbedInteropTypes` into VS. And `EmbedInteropTypes=true` means that the embedding codes used in the DLL directly into the project output file is equivalent to embedding the com reference directly into project.dll or project.exe, so that you don't have to output the com reference, thus optimizing the project.

But in some special cases,the interop layer fails when the interop type is embedded for some reasons. Your codes can't access them but only add them manually(`EmbedInteropTypes=False`). You can see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1325d24c-db0f-43a1-9780-b68a843d816b/passing-an-array-of-structs-to-a-com-interface?forum=csharpgeneral).

So please click on the `SREYELINKLib` in the `Solution Explorer` and then set the `Embed Interop Types` to `False`. Also, please do not forget to make sure that set `Copy Local` to `True`. To check it, please open xxx.csproj file and make sure that you have added the 
`<EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>`.

**In addition**, please use `Interop.SREYELINKLib.dll` not `SREYELINKLib.dll` in your project.

Hope it could help you.